# PostgreSQL dump import only imprts tables and not data

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, import, dump

I'm trying to import a postgreSQL dump into my DB. The dump is saved in a `.sql` file. I use the following command :

```
psql -U postgres -d dhris < dbDump.sql
```

and the table was created before.

The import does happen but there are tables without any data inside. What is the problem? I am using postgreSQL 9.3....

Import output :

```
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
CREATE EXTENSION
COMMENT
SET
CREATE TYPE
ALTER TYPE
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
SET
SET
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE AGGREGATE
ALTER AGGREGATE
CREATE AGGREGATE
ALTER AGGREGATE
CREATE AGGREGATE
ALTER AGGREGATE
CREATE OPERATOR
ALTER OPERATOR
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE VIEW
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE VIEW
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE VIEW
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE VIEW
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
COMMENT
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE VIEW
ALTER TABLE
CREATE VIEW
ALTER TABLE
CREATE VIEW
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE VIEW
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE VIEW
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE VIEW
ALTER TABLE
CREATE VIEW
ALTER TABLE
CREATE VIEW
ALTER TABLE
CREATE VIEW
ALTER TABLE
CREATE VIEW
ALTER TABLE
CREATE VIEW
ALTER TABLE
CREATE VIEW
ALTER TABLE
CREATE VIEW
ALTER TABLE
CREATE VIEW
ALTER TABLE
CREATE VIEW
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER SEQUENCE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER SEQUENCE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER SEQUENCE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER SEQUENCE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER SEQUENCE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER SEQUENCE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER SEQUENCE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER SEQUENCE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER SEQUENCE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER SEQUENCE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER SEQUENCE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER SEQUENCE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER SEQUENCE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE VIEW
ALTER TABLE
CREATE VIEW
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
COPY 15
COPY 5662
COPY 0
COPY 7463
COPY 111302
COPY 0
COPY 97639
COPY 114589
COPY 0
COPY 0
COPY 245
COPY 0
COPY 2
COPY 2
COPY 2
COPY 6
COPY 1
COPY 1
COPY 150440
COPY 88738
COPY 81140
COPY 328
COPY 112917
COPY 1
COPY 4
COPY 2
COPY 385037
COPY 110107
COPY 0
COPY 16
COPY 164
COPY 3
COPY 328
COPY 19
COPY 1
COPY 79861
COPY 75210
COPY 0
COPY 0
COPY 0
COPY 2249567
COPY 901494
COPY 31478
COPY 22
COPY 73
COPY 5789
COPY 4468
COPY 0
COPY 18
COPY 36
COPY 5780
COPY 5
COPY 220
COPY 25
COPY 3
COPY 4
COPY 1
COPY 3
 setval 
--------
    624
(1 row)

COPY 0
COPY 0
COPY 201027
COPY 58
COPY 15643
COPY 74222
COPY 164038
COPY 462554
COPY 0
COPY 161628
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the Import seems to be okay (in that the SQL file seemingly is getting applied), the most obvious reason looks like that the SQL file may not contain Data (and may actually be just a Schema Dump file).

To cross-check that you could try running the following command. If the command returns '0' (zero) as output, it probably indicates that the SQL file does not contain any data:

Linux: `grep "^COPY" dbDump.sql | wc -l`

Windows: `findstr "Raspberry" log.txt | find /i "Rasp" /c`

Comment: It contains data for sure. It is 600+ mb large and you command returns 68

Comment: Hmmm. I am assuming this Database isn't in active use when an application / trigger etc. is deleting data as you dump. Also, you might want to try the '-f' variant instead of the STDIN method you're using. See -f section here (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-psql.html#R1-APP-PSQL-3)

Comment: No it is not is use. I tried like this: 

psql -U postgres -d dhris --file=dbDump.sql

but it's the same result...